# Alt from json does not display on the page

Tags: javascript, json

Hi I have following javascript:

```
for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    $li = $("<li>").addClass('slide');

    //images
    for(j = 0; j < data[i].images.length; j++){
        $a = $("<a>").attr("href", data[i].images[j].href).appendTo($li);

        $("<img>")
            .attr("src", data[i].images[j].src)
            .attr("alt", data[i].images[j].alt)
            .attr("usemap", "#map" + i)
        load(imgLoadFunc)
    }
}
```

and then in jsonp file  I have:

```
[ 

{
"images": [
{
"src":"image1.jpg",
"href":"http://www.myurl.com",

"alt": "Screen 1"
        }
    ]
```

For some reason alt is not displaying anything on the page. Can someone help?

Thanks

Comment: Where are you adding `$li` and the image to the document (via `append` or similar)?

Answer (score 1):

1) Are you missing a closing "}" in the file you provided as an example?  If so that is your issue.

2) Whenever you are making a JSON file, feed the output into [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com).  You'll save yourself a lot of headaches and wild goose-chases if you know your JSON is good.

Comment: no, "}" is not missing in the code, I just place here a block that does the part.

Comment: Not in the code.  In the JSON.  Does the JSON you have pass JSONLint?

Answer (score 0):

Something is going on with your json, I think. When I try this, it works fine:

```
var data = [
    {
    "images": 
        {
        "src":"image1.jpg",
        "href":"http://www.myurl.com",

        "alt": "Screen 1"
        }
    },
    {
    "images": 
        {
        "src":"image2.jpg",
        "href":"http://www.myurl.com",

        "alt": "Screen 2"
        }
    }
];
alert(data[1].images.alt);
```

Comment: I don't see how this answers the problem reported by the OP.

Comment: I think this answer points to valid JSON working with the code given.  In the original post, it seems like he is missing closing "}".

Comment: This way data will have length attribute, normal json has no length, the json is valid. The missing } was because it is not copied as said by @marb

Answer (score 0):

Updated: The problem is with your json

Please check this json, it is tested on jslint and working fine

```
var data = [{ "images": [{"src" : "image1.jpg", "href" : "http://www.myurl.com", "alt" : "Screen 1" }, {"src" : "image2.jpg", "href" : "http://www.myurl2.com", "alt" : "Screen 2" }] } ];
```

Have updated the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/raunakkathuria/2aFp2/2/

---

This was applicable to old json data: If your data is the json variable that you are accessing then you need to change the logic, json has no length property, so `data.length` is not right, if your images in data contains all the images you want then you do `data.images.length`

Please check the working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/raunakkathuria/2aFp2/1/

Comment: I'm using 'data.images.lenth', please check my code again. Sorry, your example does not work..

Comment: I was saying about data.length, as json object has no length property. Can you check (alert/console.log) if it is going inside first loop? What in my example does not work? Its loading fine for me.

Comment: I do not see image  alt being displayed on your example as well. And yes, alert is showing each alt value. My though  is I'll have to check json file. Thanks

Comment: Which browser you using to check the fiddle, cos I can see Screen 1 alt in my example and I am talking about for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { this block whether it is entering this block? because the json you have posted will not have any length property. Thanks Raunak